# Qt Window flags set to Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint but not working

Tags: c++, qt, always-on-top

I have create a 'flash' window to show an image during the application start-up.  The image is displayed, in my derived QMainWindow constructor I set the flags:

```
setWindowFlags(Qt::CustomizeWindowHint
             | Qt::FramelessWindowHint                   
             | Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint);
```

However, when another window is created I am able to drag this new window in-front of the splash window which I don't want.  I want the dragged window to be behind the splash window until it is remove.

I search online and what I've set should work but it doesn't.  I'm using Qt Creator 4.9.0 Based on Qt 5.12.2

My system is an iMAC (Retina 5K, 27-inch, Late 2015).

[Edit] I used the code below to test and prove the fault I'm having, my application window needs to be modal, but I want the splash window to be always on top.

```
    #include <QMainWindow>
    #include <QApplication>

    int main(int argc, char ** argv)
    {
       QApplication app(argc, argv);

       QMainWindow * mw = new QMainWindow();
       mw->setWindowFlags(Qt::CustomizeWindowHint | Qt::FramelessWindowHint | Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint);
       mw->resize(500, 500);
       mw->show();

       QMainWindow * secondWindow = new QMainWindow();
       secondWindow->setWindowModality(Qt::ApplicationModal); // <- This breaks the always on top flag
       secondWindow->resize(500, 500);
       secondWindow->show();
       return app.exec();
    }
```

I've tried setting both windows to be modal, that doesn't help either.

Comment: Have you considered using a [`QSplashScreen`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsplashscreen.html)?

Comment: @TrebledJ, probably have, but I wrote this originally sometime ago and it does exactly what I want and need except stay on top...which should be possible given the name of the flag.

Comment: What window are you dragging in front of it? One you created? What flags are you using to create the other window? Do other application windows show in front?

Comment: @Nick, I want all windows created by my application to appear behind the splash.  The windows for all windows are using the defaults except the splash which is as I've posted.

Comment: It may not be a problem with this window is what I'm getting at. Can you show the code of the other windows being created?

Answer (score 1):

The following program works for me; does it work for you?  (on my Mac, running this program opens an empty gray window that is always in front of all other windows)

```
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
   QApplication app(argc, argv);

   QMainWindow * mw = new QMainWindow;
   mw->setWindowFlags(Qt::CustomizeWindowHint | Qt::FramelessWindowHint | Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint);
   mw->resize(500, 500);
   mw->show();

   QMainWindow * secondWindow = new QMainWindow;
   secondWindow->resize(500, 500);
   secondWindow->show();
   return app.exec();
}
```

If this program does work for you, then you'll need to figure out how your own program differs from this one; OTOH if this program shows the same misbehavior you are seeing in your own program, then it may be there is a bug in the version of Qt that you are using.  (I'm testing with Qt 5.12.2 on a 2018 Mac mini running OS/X 10.14.4, FWIW)

Comment: Its not the same, create another window in the same application and then make sure that the 2nd window does not and cannot appear in front of the original.

Comment: Okay, done.  See updated text.  Feel free to come up with your own program that demonstrates the fault; if people can compile a program and observe the fault for themselves, that allows them to experiment with the problem and figure out the entry conditions, rather than having to just guess about what might be going wrong.

Comment: Thank you, your code works, I'm really not sure where the problem is...looking into it now.

Comment: I think I can see where my problem is, but I'm not sure why it ever worked at all.  In my main window I create a new widget and then treat this as a window, this is where the problem comes from, if you modify your code so instead of another QMainWindow, use "QWidget* pobjWin = new QWidget();"  then use all the same methods as for a main window and finally call show....this new widget doesn't obey the window rules.

Comment: Just changed the routine to use QMainWindow instead of QWidget, still the same problem...

Comment: Found it, I believe this is a but in Qt, the cause of the problem is after a call to setStyleSheet(), I am just passing this "background-color:#ff0000;color:#ffff00;" which causes the window background to be red and the text to be yellow, but after this the other window is no longer on top, without a call to setStyleSheet, everything works.  The call to setStyleSheet is on the 2nd window NOT the window which is supposed to be on top.

Comment: If you have found a toy program that reproduces the fault, I encourage you to edit your question and paste it there (indent the code four spaces so that it will be formatted correctly)

Comment: Having copied your code again and trying to replicate the problem it doesn't behave the same in your code, so I'm now scratching my head again.

Comment: Found it....see my post in the edit section, where I have included your code with a modification to show the cause.